# Problem in calling SOAP web service (written in PHP) from ASP.Net

Tags: php, asp.net, web-services, soap

I am trying to call a webservice, written in PHP from ASP.Net.
I have added Web Reference using "Add Web Reference".
The url is: http://mikikard.com/public/webservice?wsdl
In Add Web Reference Window, I can see the list of functions. 
But, When I try to build the Website, It gives the following Error:

***Unable to import binding 'SoaptestBinding' from namespace 'http://mikikard.com/public/webservice'.***

Can you please let me know what's going wrong?

Thanks,

Ashish Thakker.

Answer (score 0):

I recently tried accessing reporting services via soap from Java servlet. Here is a fine article may be it will give you some other ideas.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/christophputz/archive/2010/05/07/accessing-ms-reporting-services-with-java.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage